# How to find the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Not sure where to even start at this one. I think I could get it to this form:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\sqrt{(x+1)(x-1)}}{x}$$

Why cant I do this any further?
EDIT:
That square root really messes me up often and I get confused about what to do next when I see it

Comment: **If** you are a calculus student, note that this limit is, by definition, $f'(0)$ where $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}&=&\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}{x(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-(1-x^2)}{x(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{x(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}=0.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}= \frac{x^2}{x(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})} $$ Can you take it from there?